# Why does this es6 generator function crash the babel compiler?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I copied this code from an es6 generator functions tutorial into babel's online compiler in order to see what the generated code would look like

```
function* count(){
    for (var x = 0; true; x++) {
        yield x
    }
}

for (var x of count()) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

The following options were enabled: `es2015, es2016, react, stage-2`.
Upon pasting, the tab froze and crashed (consistently across a few attempts).

#### Links:

The generator functions tutorial this is taken from: https://www.promisejs.org/generators/

The babel compiler (official): https://babeljs.io/repl/

#### Question

1. What should the above should compile to?
2. Does babel require some sort of option enabled to support generator functions in the browser?
3. Why would the above input crash the babel compiler? (maybe unanswerable)

Comment: It crashes if you have "evaluate" checked, because this is an infinite loop. It works fine if you don't evaluate it

Comment: wow, such a stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing that out, nothing wrong with babel

Comment: I'm not sure how to "mark as closed" but if you put that as an answer I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about the use of the Babel.js online tool, rather than about generators or ES2016 more broadly.

The problem is that your code creates an infinite loop. It is possible to compile code that produces an infinite loop. *Executing* that code, however, will crash your browser. You have set the Babel website tool to evaluate the code.

If you untick the "evaluate" option or compile the code from the command line, Babel will cope with the transpilation just fine.